# Why doesn't my linecount in C work?

Tags: c, line-count

I'm trying to read a text file but before that I want to know how many elements I'm going to read. So I need to count the lines of a text file. So far, I have this:

```
int getLinecount (char *file) 
{
    int ch, count = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n'); 
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return count;
}
```

This worked pretty fine. I have changed nothing about the text file and still it prints 130,000 though the file only has 10,000 lines.
The only thing I wrote in my main is:

```
linecount = getLinecount("...");
```

I am really curious where the error is. Also, is there a better option of getting the linecount?

Comment: Tracing this through using a debugger would have pointed you to this `;` immediately.

Comment: Learn your compiler & compile with full warnings on. For example gcc's `-Wextra` option catches that & outputs: `warning: empty body in an if-statement`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a trailing semicolon `;` after your `if` statement. Then, the block is always executed:

```
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: How could I overlook that and how did it get there? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
if (ch == '\n');
```

to:

```
if (ch == '\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

Trailing semi-colon after the `if`: remove it. With the trailing semi-colon the code is equivalent to:

```
if (ch == '\n') {}
count++;
```

meaning that `count` is incremented for every iteration of the loop (every `char` in the file).

Answer (score 1):

you have trailing semicolon to delete after `if`

and for reading files, better use this code 
:

```
while((fgets(blahblahblah)) != NULL) {
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine except for a semicolon (`;`), which should be removed from the line

```
if (ch == '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `;` issue mentioned by others, an alternative solution can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4278875) post as he explains why he does things the way he does.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the OS you are using to create and view this file.

Copied from [PHP Echo Line Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255511/php-echo-line-breaks):

- '\n' is a linux/unix line break
- '\r' is a classic mac line break [OS X uses the above unix \n]
- '\r'+'\n' is a windows line break

Comment: He opens the file in text mode, so the linebreak is '\n' no matter the platform