# load file content into structure only if file exists or use default values

Tags: c, arrays, struct, structure

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct my_data {
 char* name;
}my_data;

my_data data[]={
    { .name = "Peter" },
    { .name = "James" },
    { .name = "John" },
    { .name = "Mike" }
};


void loaddata()
{
    FILE * in;
    if((in = fopen("data.txt","rt")) != NULL) {
        printf("start loading\n");
        int i = 0;
        while(!feof(in))
        {
            fscanf(in,"%s", &data[i].name);
            printf("%s\n",data[i].name);
            i++;
        };
    }
    else
        printf("loading not required\n");
    fclose(in);
}
```

And it gives me a "killed" error.

How can I load data from file data.txt into existing structure and in case file doesn't exist to use default values which were defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need "&" in:

```
fscanf(in,"%s", &data[i].name);
```

and no need to close filestream if it's not opened.

```
void loaddata()
{
    FILE * in;
    if((in = fopen("data.txt","rt")) != NULL) {
        printf("start loading\n");
        int i = 0;
        while(!feof(in))
        {
            fscanf(in,"%s", data[i].name);
            printf("%s\n",data[i].name);
            i++;
        };
        fclose(in); /* need closing */
    }
    else
        printf("loading not required\n");
    /* no need closing */
}
```

UPD: create structure with allocated memory, not pointer. Pointer accesses part of program, not memory, so you cannot save data there.

```
typedef struct my_data {
    char name[10];
}my_data;
```

Comment: w\o & I get Segmentation fault

Comment: move close(in); into if{ }

Comment: I'm using an older version of gcc, but the program must compatible with any, right?

Comment: Sorry,  "killed" error was caused misplaced close().
fscanf(in,"%s", &data[i].name); use is correct.
Also, use temporary vaiable between reading from file and saving to structure.

Comment: I still get that killed error if file exists, otherwise it's working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37738/discussion-between-oleg-olivson-and-sam-reina)

Comment: yes, you're right, I forgot to modify that. now it's working. glad you noticed that :)

Comment: I have another issue now, with the array size. If the number of lines in file is less than those in the defined array list I get a lot of empty elements.

Comment: [count lines of a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278845/count-the-lines-of-a-file-in-c)