# Closing C++ File Stream is not Opened

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream, ofstream

Suppose you declare an instance of `std::ifstream` or `std::ofstream` but `is_open()` returns `0`

Example:

```
std::ifstream file("myfile.txt");
if (!file.is_open()) {
    printf("Could not open file\n");
    return;
}
```

Since the file never opened, do I still need to call `file.close()` after the `printf` statement?

Comment: Think about it for a minute. The file is *not* open. What is there to close?

Comment: You usually never have to call `close()` explicitly, it's done automatically when the instance goes out of scope.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Not everything in programming is so intuitive. I would assume not, but you never know. Probably should've asked in chat since it's a yes/no question. However the extra knowledge that comes with the "slightly longer than expected answer" is always appreciated.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What if I declare an `ifstream` to check for a file's existence but then depending on conditions I need to open an `ofstream` to edit the file? I _would_ need to close it then right?

Comment: In the if statement the stream object can be directly used as a boolean expression. That is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only close an *open* file (similar to how you cannot close an already closed door - there is nothing to be done).

Extra note: Please do not combine the C I/O library (X`printf` family of functions) with the C++ I/O library (iostreams).

Consider using code like this:

```
std::ifstream file("myfile.txt");
if (!file.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "Could not open file\n";
    return;
}
```

Edit (reasons not to use C IO API and C++ IO API together):

- Using both APIs imposes synchronization between them, with priority towards the C API (i.e. the C api remains as fast, but IO streams will become slower, due to synchronization requirements).
- It is inconsistent, using two very different concepts/abstraction levels for the same task. In more complex code, you will have to write twice the error handling (they impose different styles of error handling in client code), have both their limitations and combine their bad aspects (C API is prone to buffer overflows/security issues on reading and fails silently, unless you pay lots of attention to writing/maintenance of each API call, C++ API calls can be verbose).

They do not need to be particularly close (or far) appart, it is simply a bad programming practice.

This is similar to using a generic ODBC C API for reading table1 of your database, and ActiveX Data Objects for reading table2 in the same database, and the same program, or using Qt for your development, then hacking over it with raw WinAPI calls: you have twice the problems to solve (and many times end up implementing the solution to the same problems twice).

Comment: In addition, even if you did have to close it (which you don't) the ifstream is going out of scope at the return statement and being destructed which would implicitly close it.

Comment: Why shouldn't `printf` and `iostream` be used together (for example `printf("File opened\n");` which would not go in `std::err`)? How far apart do they need to be (e.g. not in same scope, method, class, file, etc)?